# VLC in Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line-arguments, vlc

I am attempting to write a very basic Bash script that will accomplish the same thing as this command line:

```
cvlc \
  'rtsp://192.168.0.66/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&authbasic=xxxxxxxxx?tcp' \
   --sout file/mp4:/mnt/recordings/camera16_2014_10_03_13.mp4 \
   --run-time=60 vlc://quit
```

Entering this into the command line works and I get the expected 60 second MP4 file.  Putting this into a bash script, I cannot seem to get all of the arguments passed to VLC correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
camname="CAMERA16"
token="_"
ipadd="192.168.0.66"
runtime="60"
cvlc "rtsp://$ipadd/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&authbasic=xxxxxxxxx?tcp --sout file/mp4:/mnt/recordings/$camname$token$(date +$Y_%m_%d_$H_$M).mp4 --run-time=$runtime vlc://quit"
```

Running this script launches VLC, not headless, and ignores the other arguments.  It does not write to a file and it never quits.  It simply connects VLC to the stream and plays the stream.

I have tried several different ways of quoting the arguments with no success.  All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those need to be separate arguments to the `cvlc` command.  By putting them all in one big double-quoted string, you turn them into a single argument, which won't work.  Put each of the arguments in its own set of double-quotes; don't put the spaces inside the quotes:

```
cvlc "rtsp://$ipadd/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&authbasic=xxxxxxxxx?tcp" \
     --sout "file/mp4:/mnt/recordings/$camname$token$(date +$Y_%m_%d_$H_$M).mp4" \
     --run-time="$runtime" vlc://quit
```

I used quoted newlines to split across multiple lines for legibility; it can also be just one long line without the `\`s.